# Different virtual hosts for same website but different pages

Tags: apache, virtualhost

My web server directory is as follows:

```
var/www/html/site-part-1
var/www/html/site-part-2
```

In site-part-1, I have a wordpress installation, and when a person lands on my site  by google organic / direct whatever when they type in the domain into addres bar it will take user to site-part-1

Currently site-part-1 is operational with the virtual host configuration directory root directory set to `var/www/html/site-part-1`

But I have a completely different system in site-part-2, that is built with python which I will be accessing via a link from the wordpress site.

example.com (site-part-1) will have a link, and it will take the user to my website `example.com/my/directory` and in `/my/directory` will be the contents of site-part-2

It may have worked sticking site-part-2 in the wordpress site folder but for cleanliness I put it into seperate folder

Does anyone know how I should go about setting up my apache settings so that both directories work together?

Comment: Alias /my/directory /var/www/html/site-part-2 maybe ?

Comment: VirtualHost need to have some criteria to distinguish between themselves.  If you only have 1 domain on the same IP and the same port, you are stuck with 1 VH.  `Alias` like @AndreGelinas proposed looks good in that context.

Comment: Cheers I'll give that a go and feedback how i get on